# Find traveling distance between line and point

Tags: point, line, distance, shapely

Is there a clever way to traverse a line string up until a point and return the distance to that point? As an example:

```
a = LineString([(1, 1), (9, 1), (9, 6), (4, 6), (4, 3)])
p = Point((4,4,))
```

The distance from the start of a, to point p would be:

```
  8  # 9-1
  5  # 6-1
  5  # 9-4
+ 2  # 2, p intesects line segment after 2 units
= 20
```

I suppose I can just traverse the line and summing up the distance until p intersects the line segment, and calculate the last bit, but I get a feeling that there is something more elegant in the API that I haven't yet discovered.

Never heard of shapely until today, and I'm quite impressed by what I have seen so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `project()` method.

> `project` returns the distance along this geometric object to a point nearest the other object.

```
a = LineString([(1, 1), (9, 1), (9, 6), (4, 6), (4, 3)])
p = Point((4,4,))
a.project(p)
#20.0
```

Note that if you define `a` as `LineString([(4, 3), (4, 6), (9, 6), (9, 1), (1, 1)])`, you get `1.0`.